# Blazor FluentValidation how to Inject dependency to AbstractValidator

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor, fluentvalidation

I am using FluentValidator for a current Blazor-Server Project.

Now i need to inject my database service class for validate duplication and stuff like that.

```
 public class StockValidator : AbstractValidator<LagertypModel>
{
    private StockOverviewService _stockservice;

    public StockValidator(StockOverviewService stockservice)
    {
        _stockservice = stockservice;
        RuleFor(LagertypModel => LagertypModel.Lagertyp).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(4).Must(Lagertyp => {
            return _stockservice.validateStockTypeCU(Lagertyp).Result;
        });


    }
}
```

But when i do that i get the error that StockValidator needs to have a parameterless contructor.

How can i inject my dependency now?

Comment: If `StockValidator` is  registered as a DI service, then the DI container will inject the `StockOverviewService` automatically.  How are you trying to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Where you instantiate your **StockValidator** class make sure you pass your service into it like so:

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<StockOverviewService>();
```

**StockOverviewService.cs**

```
private StockValidator_validator;
public StockOverviewService(LiveConnectionString connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
            _validator = new StockValidator(this);
        }
```

**StockValidator.cs**

```
public class StockValidator : AbstractValidator<LagertypModel>
{
    private StockOverviewService _stockservice;

    public StockValidator(StockOverviewService stockservice)
    {
        _stockservice = stockservice;
        RuleFor(LagertypModel => LagertypModel.Lagertyp).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(4).Must(Lagertyp => {
            return _stockservice.validateStockTypeCU(Lagertyp).Result;
        });


    }
}
```

Assuming your **StockOverviewService** uses async methods for accessing a DB/Api, I don't recommend this approach because you're making the code run synchronously here:

```
return _stockservice.validateStockTypeCU(Lagertyp).Result;
```

but it will work.

Comment: But your StockValidator.cs will throq an exception due to the error i explained in the first post. The thing is, i am using the validator only for a webform and nothing else. I just want to specify some rules amd validations while filling out the form(devexpress blazor). Isnt there any possibility to inject just my serviceclass?

Comment: I recreated your scenario to the best I could and tested it on my end. The StockService is available within the StockValidator class. Are you not using DependencyInjection or something? If you are, you need to inject the service this way: _validator = new StockValidator(this)

Comment: Of course i am using dependency injection for my StockService class but not for the validator. I have a blazor component <FluentValidator> which is placed inside the <Form> component where i can then just add the TValidator Parameter with the "StockValidator" class as attribute and then its working.